# How can I get real-time CDOR rate, swaps, and options pricing data refreshed on a daily basis in Excel?

Tags: bloomberg, excel, vba

I'm currently using "Bloomberg Anywhere", which is the same as Bloomberg Terminal except account-specific rather than PC/hardware-specific. I currently have to refresh the rates every morning at exactly 8:15AM for use in our Excel model, which sends the pertinent information to other teams to make decisions off of for the day.

My problem is that I'd much rather automate the action of refreshing the rates every morning at the same time, so that I don't have to physically be around but rather maybe just keep my computer on or something. I have introductory experience with VBA from my university courses, but otherwise have more comprehensive experience with Python and Javascript, so I think if VBA scripting is involved it shouldn't be too much of a challenge. What I am looking for is some sort of feedback on feasibility and complexity from anyone who has experience auto-refreshing rates or other data using the Bloomberg Excel add-in and likely some VBA?

Comment: You will have to be physically around at most an hour prior because inactive Anywhere sessions will be terminated after one hour of inactivity.

Comment: As long as you don't login on another device you can still use the API even if you have been logged off.

Comment: @assylias Yes but he's not using the API, he's using the Excel plug-in (which in turn does use the API) but gets closed with the inactivity shutdown

Answer (score 3):

Bloomberg `WAPI` (same API for all supported languages, including excel vba) refreshes as soon as you send the request. No need to do some awkward refresh of standard Bloomberg formulas.

Generally speaking though, this sounds a lot like non-compliant use of data. Vendors are very strict with how to download and share (essentially no sharing at all). Partially because it is their business, but also because there are different rules for data dissemination from exchanges etc. If you have some sort of enterprise data license, you do not even need a terminal to use the API and can get bulk requests at any time you wish automatically.

Comment: Yes, their license probably doesn't allow to download data from a Bloomberg API and "send the pertinent information to other teams". They shouldn't do it without paying Bloomberg for this use of Bloomberg's data.